# How do I position my JButtons at the bottom of my applet?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

/**
 * Created by joshuaogunnote on 31/10/2015.
 */

public class Applet2 extends JApplet {

    JTextField value1, value2;

    public void init() {

        JLabel prompt = new JLabel("Please enter a word");
        JLabel prompt1 = new JLabel("Please enter a letter");

        value1 = new JTextField(3);
        value2 = new JTextField(3);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(prompt);
        add(value1);


        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(prompt1);
        add(value2);


        JButton but = new JButton("Add word");
        JButton but1 = new JButton("Clear");
        JButton but2 = new JButton("Remove first occurrence");
        JButton but3 = new JButton("Remove all occurrences");
        JButton but4 = new JButton("Display all words begging with certain letter");
        JButton but5 = new JButton("Search");

        JPanel butPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel butPanel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel butPanel2 = new JPanel();

        butPanel.add(but);
        butPanel.add(but1);
        butPanel1.add(but2);
        butPanel1.add(but3);
        butPanel2.add(but4);
        butPanel2.add(but5);
```

Here is where I am trying to determine the position of the buttons on the Applet. I am using the BorderLayout.SOUTH to try and get the buttons to appear at the bottom of the applet but it is not working. How do I get the buttons to appear at the bottom of the Applet?

```
        add(butPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(butPanel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(butPanel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }


}
```

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 2):

You can only add one component to a BorderLayout position. So create a new JPanel to hold the buttons, add the buttons to it, and add that to the south position. But note that BorderLayout constants will only work if the container (here `this`) uses BorderLayout!:

```
JButton but = new JButton("Add word");
JButton but1 = new JButton("Clear");
JButton but2 = new JButton("Remove first occurrence");
JButton but3 = new JButton("Remove all occurrences");
JButton but4 = new JButton("Display all words begging with certain letter");
JButton but5 = new JButton("Search");

JButton[] buttons = {but, but1, but2, but3, but4, but5};
JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
for(JButton btn : buttons) {
    bottomPanel.add(btn);
}

// note this will only work if the layout for *this* is in fact BorderLayout!
add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

A more complete example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Foo extends JPanel {
    private JTextField value1;
    private JTextField value2;

    public Foo() {
        JLabel prompt = new JLabel("Please enter a word");
        JLabel prompt1 = new JLabel("Please enter a letter");

        value1 = new JTextField(3);
        value2 = new JTextField(3);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(prompt);
        topPanel.add(value1);

        topPanel.add(prompt1);
        topPanel.add(value2);

        JButton but = new JButton("Add word");
        JButton but1 = new JButton("Clear");
        JButton but2 = new JButton("Remove first occurrence");
        JButton but3 = new JButton("Remove all occurrences");
        JButton but4 = new JButton(
                "Display all words begging with certain letter");
        JButton but5 = new JButton("Search");

        JButton[] buttons = { but, but1, but2, but3, but4, but5 };
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        for (JButton btn : buttons) {
            bottomPanel.add(btn);
        }

        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(30, 40)), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Foo mainPanel = new Foo();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

which displays as:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You set the layout to a FlowLayout, so you can't use the constraints of a BorderLayout. Don't do that. The default layout of a JApplet is a BorderLayout, so there is no need to change the layout.

Also, you can only add a single component to any constraint of the BorderLayout.

So create a panel that uses a FlowLayout. Add your buttons to the panel Then add that panel to the BorderLayout.SOUTH.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for working examples